# Of and from, are they interchangeable in some cases?

Tags: ielts

i was reading this letter for IELTS and i was not sure if this was the proper usage because i thought of an alternative:

> My name is Mathew Abraham and I am writing this letter regarding an important document I forgot in a taxi ***from*** your company last week

is it the same if i change the part of "from your company" with an "of your company"?

It would be like this in the end:

> My name is Mathew Abraham and I am writing this letter regarding an important document I forgot in a taxi ***of*** your company last week

I get confused in these cases where it sounds to me as if either of those two options would be ok, but I'm not 100% sure if that's the case in this particular example.

Comment: Neither one. I would use "an important document I forgot in your company's taxi last week". If you need the prepositional phrase, then "an important document I forgot in a taxi *belonging to/operated by* your company last week"

Answer (score 3):

Don't underestimate the power of the possessive form! I would say the following:

> My name is Mathew Abraham, and I am writing this letter regarding an important document I forgot in **one of your taxis** last week.

Many times, using the possessive instead of "the X of Y" is more concise and more natural.

Comment: Yes you are right, it sounds much better. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I agree that godel9's answer is the most *idiomatic*, to answer your question:

"From" points to the origin of the object:

> This is a statue **from** ancient Mesopotamia.
>
> These are excerpts **from** the witness' deposition.

"Of" (generally) refers to something *about* or *related to* the object:

> This is a description **of** ancient Mesopotamia.
>
> These are witness accounts **of** the incident.

So "a taxi *of* your company" does not sound idiomatic to me.  I prefer "a taxi *from* (originating at) your company."

Note that "of" can also refer to the (metaphorical or literal) *composition* of something, which is different from its origin.  Examples:

> He is a man **of** means.
>
> ... and that government **of** the people, by the people, for the people, shall not perish from the earth.  [source](http://www.abrahamlincolnonline.org/lincoln/speeches/gettysburg.htm)

You might also see idiomatic uses of "of" that *seem* to mean the same thing as "from", but which also imply composition:

> He is a man **of** his time.

This might be used to describe someone whose dress, mannerisms, thoughts, prejudices, etc. are all typical of a certain time in the past -- that is, he is completely *composed* of those things.